# custom QAbstractNetworkCache implementation; QAbstractNetworkCache::insert(QIODevice *device) device has no data

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8, qtcore, qiodevice

I am attempting to build my own custom `QAbstractNetworkCache` implementation for use with `QNetworkAccessManager`.

I am having trouble with `QAbstractNetworkCache::insert(QIODevice *device)`; inside this method, the device always arrives with 0 bytes to read from.

As I understand, the `QIODevice*` that is returned from `QAbstractNetworkCache::prepare(const QNetworkCacheMetaData &metaData)` is going to be filled with data and used as a parameter to `QAbstractNetworkCache::insert(QIODevice *device)` method once `QNetworkAccessManager` finishes downloading.

So I have prepared a `QBuffer` to be this container, but whenever `QAbstractNetworkCache::insert(QIODevice *device)` is getting called, it always arrives with nothing in it `(device->bytesAvailable() == 0)`

```
QIODevice* NetworkCachePrivate::prepare(const QNetworkCacheMetaData &metaData) {

        if (!metaData.isValid() || !metaData.url().isValid() || cacheDir.isEmpty()) return 0;

        QIODevice* device = 0;

        QString hash = hexMD5(metaData.url().toString());

        QScopedPointer<QBuffer> buffer(new QBuffer);

        if (buffer->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
        {
                qDebug() << "BUFFER READY";
                device = buffer.take();
                deviceMapping[device] = qMakePair(hash, metaData);
        }

        return device;
}

void NetworkCachePrivate::insert(QIODevice *device) {
        if (deviceMapping.contains(device))
        {
                QPair<QString, QNetworkCacheMetaData> pair = deviceMapping[device];
                QString fileName;
                fileName += cacheDir;
                fileName += QLatin1String("/");
                fileName += pair.first;

                qDebug() << "DEVICE BYTES" << device->bytesAvailable(); //ALWAYS 0!!!! :(
                QFile file(fileName);
                if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
                {
                        qint64 size = file.write(device->readAll());
                        if (size <= 0)
                        {
                                file.remove();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                qDebug() << "FILE WROTE " << size;
                                cacheSize += size;
                        }
                }
                deviceMapping.remove(device);
                delete device;
        }
}

QNetworkCacheMetaData NetworkCachePrivate::metaData (const QUrl &url ) {
    QString fileName;
    fileName += cacheDir; 
    fileName += QLatin1String("/"); 
    fileName += hexMD5(url.toString());

    QNetworkCacheMetaData data;

    if (!QFile::exists(fileName))
        return data;

    data.setUrl(url); 
    data.setExpirationDate(QDateTime::currentDateTime().addYears(1));
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't that `QBuffer` simply returns 0 because it's a random access I/O device, and its current position is at the end of the buffer (because the writer just filled it in with data)?

Comment: Hm, could be. Will try to seek it to the beginning in a moment.

Comment: Yep, *facepalm*. It was so obvious :( . Thank you.

Comment: @peppe PS. you may want to copy the comment as an answer so I'll be able to accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As peppe also pointed out in the comment, you need to seek the `QBuffer` to the beginning after the write and before the read as per the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qbuffer.html#details):

> QBuffer allows you to access a QByteArray using the QIODevice interface. The QByteArray is treated just as a standard random-accessed file. Example:

```
QBuffer buffer;
char ch;

buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);
buffer.write("Qt rocks!");
*** buffer.seek(0); ***
buffer.getChar(&ch);  // ch == 'Q'
buffer.getChar(&ch);  // ch == 't'
buffer.getChar(&ch);  // ch == ' '
buffer.getChar(&ch);  // ch == 'r'
```

To be more concrete for your code, you would need to insert the statement like this:

```
...
device.seek(0);
qDebug() << "DEVICE BYTES" << device->bytesAvailable(); //NOT 0 ANYMORE!!!! :)
...
```